# How to add text to a chart by excel macro?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-charts

Using the following codes to add text to a chart by excel macro?
When compiled to a module, it shows "object doesn't support this property or method", any suggestion or revised codes really appreciated. Thanks

```
Set myDocument = Ch.Chart

  myDocument.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 382, 266, 122, 20).Select

    Selection.ShapeRange.TextFrame.Characters.Text = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(6, 8)

   With Selection.ShapeRange.TextFrame.Characters

    .Font.Name = "Tahoma"

    .Font.Size = 10

    .Font.Bold = msoTrue

   End With
```

Comment: Which line causes the error?  Also, how have you defined `Ch`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to select the chart before adding your textbox, etc.  Your code can be re-written as follows...

```
Dim theChartObj As ChartObject
Set theChartObj = Worksheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects("Chart 1") 'change the sheet and chart names accordingly

Dim theChart As Chart
Set theChart = theChartObj.Chart

Dim theTextBox As Shape
Set theTextBox = theChart.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 382, 266, 122, 20)

With theTextBox.TextFrame.Characters
    .Text = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(6, 8).Value
    With .Font
        .Name = "Tahoma"
        .Size = 10
        .Bold = msoTrue
    End With
End With
```

Comment: copy your code, only change the 2nd line as :    Set theChartObj = Sheets(1).ChartObject(plot)      , that shows bug "application-denied or object defined error.  what is the possible reason? the plot is the chart name

Comment: If the chart is located within the workbook running the code, you'll need to qualify your reference `Set theChartObj = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).ChartObjects(plot)`.